# Show related questions when reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review, related-questions

I just started to use the new review process for First Posts.

Could we have the list of related questions shown when we review a question, as it helps to see duplicate questions?

I was reviewing close votes and would like it there as well. The close vote cast by others was for non duplicate reasons but it was such a simple question it must have been asked before.

Comment: Was just about to request the same feature and happened upon this question. It would help with flagging duplicate questions as mentioned by Mark.

Comment: @Ren Have a look at the script below if you have GreaseMonkey.

Comment: @Asad I don't have GreaseMonkey (yet). I was hoping this could be added as a feature to the site for all reviewers. It doesn't seem like that is going to happen though and your solution does what I want :)

Comment: I was just about to ask this question myself and discovered this duplicate of my question. Why has this not either been implemented or explained why not? This Q is 2.5 years old! It's a nuisance not to have this built in.

Comment: Regarding the bounty: I wouldn’t say you need this on *all* queues, it doesn’t seem too useful in first answers :P

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica actually yes - as if that answer is the same as an answer on a different question then you should be flagging the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this really needs to be added as a standard feature.

I find it a little irritating to have to leave the review queue to perform a thorough review, and in my mind a thorough review should include checking for duplicates.

Part of the purpose of the having the First Posts Review is to educate new users, part of that education should be to show them that they should search before asking and that duplicates should be closed. If the question is left open long enough to gather an answer and possibly even a few up-votes the opposite lesson is received.

Comment: and if you do the full correct review someone else will have clicked on the review and passed or failed it, Good reviews are penalised

Answer (score 7):

## Screenshot:

The related questions sidebar item is similar to the one on your right, but indicates which questions have accepted answers by coloring them green, additionally displaying the number of answers for each question in parentheses.

[image: screenshot of First posts review queue]

## Description:

This is a short [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script that adds related questions to the sidebar, similar to how you see them on questions:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        firstposts
// @namespace   firstposts
// @include     *stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){
    if(settings.url == "/review/next-task"){
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (response.postId){
            $.getJSON("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/" + response.postId + "/related?site=stackoverflow", function(data){
                var items = data.items;
                if(items.length){
                    var container = $('<div class="related" />');
                    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                        var link = $('<a class="question-hyperlink" />').attr({href : items[i].link, target: '_blank'}).css('color', items[i].is_answered?"rgb(50,200,50)":"rgb(61,61,61)").text(items[i].title + " (" + items[i].answer_count + ")");
                        $('<div class="spacer" />').append(link).appendTo(container);
                    }
                    $('<div class="module sidebar-related" />').append($('<h4 />').text('Related')).append(container).appendTo($('.sidebar'));
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a minified version for bookmarking:

```js
javascript:(function(){$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e,t,n){if(n.url=="/review/next-task"){var%20r=JSON.parse(t.responseText);if(r.postId){$.getJSON("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/"+r.postId+"/related?site=stackoverflow",function(e){var%20t=e.items;if(t.length){var%20n=$('<div%20class="related"%20/>');for(var%20r=0;r<t.length;r++){var%20i=$('<a%20class="question-hyperlink"%20/>').attr({href:t[r].link,target:"_blank"}).css("color",t[r].is_answered?"rgb(50,200,50)":"rgb(61,61,61)").text(t[r].title+"%20("+t[r].answer_count+")");$('<div%20class="spacer"%20/>').append(i).appendTo(n)}$('<div%20class="module%20sidebar-related"%20/>').append($("<h4%20/>").text("Related")).append(n).appendTo($(".sidebar"))}})}}})})();
```

If any one finds any bugs / has ideas for improvements / has any ideas on how to turn this into an addon, I'm all ears.

Comment: Awarded the bounty to this answer :) I would still prefer if it were to be built in as a feature of the site for all reviewers to use though :P

Comment: @Ren Totally agree. It shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: 2ren is it worth the bounty as doesn't Greasemonkey only work on Firefox

Comment: @Mark This works as a bookmark as well, across browsers. Btw, Greasemonkey works on Chrome as well.

Comment: @Mark I've added a bookmarkable version to the answer