# Reviewing questions from users with low reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, review

Personally I'm getting completely fed up with SO lately. It is both heaven and hell in one place.

I'm guessing at least 6 of the 10 questions posted will be either deleted due to low quality, or duplicates because people tend to post here before using Google..

Wouldn't it be a good idea to have questions from users with lets say under 100 reputation reviewed before they are actually published on the site?

Comment: SO, or Meta.SO?

Comment: Isn't that why [this has been built](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts)?

Comment: @BackinaFlash Yes, but it is definitely not covering the fact that the newest-questions are completely full of spam-questions..

Answer (score 1):

Post of new users are already reviewed in the review queue's. Although they are directly posted.

And some are closed during the review.

Comment: But the tools when reviewing don't help They dom't not show linked [questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147513/show-related-questions-when-reviewing-a-first-question) so hard to spot a dup. ALso the don't allow time for the user to respond to a comment requesting clarification or a change